Order sizing in HFT market-making (Avellaneda-Stoikov)
I am building a market making bot, using Stoikov's model to find optimal bid and ask prices.
However, I'm confused to as what my order sizing should be.
For now, I used this calculation:
normalisedVolume = m15vol / dailyvol
m15qty = balance * normalisedVolume
time_per_trade = 900000 / totalm15trades
qtypertrades = m15qty / time_per_trade
This is based on finding the average volume within each 15 minute time-frame throughout the day. I find the 15m volume given by daily volume, and multiply that with my balance to spread my balance across the day. Then I find how frequently a trade is happening within EACH 15 minute timeframe and divide the m15qty (my balance*normalizedVolume) to the the qty in USD per trade.
This assumes I'm the only market-maker on the exchange and that I will hit every trade.
This seems a bit too complicated. I lose track of the logic here everytime I read it.
Is there a more optimal/simpler way of choosing position sizes?

The order sizing has nothing to do with that paper. The paper attempts to give a solution for quotes based on eod net position and each trade unit is relative to each other. As in, 1 unit size vs 10 unit size will yield the same result because it makes the assumption when your LO is executed, it is executed in full. If you start placing orders larger than the minimum trade size, you have to workout what happens when a partial fill occurs.
The paper does not give a solution (or discuss) for the overall risk profile of your company (self). You would need to look at papers discussing your portfolio management, since your question is an existential risk problem.
As a simple example, you could find your trade size based on a type of mean-variance framework, and would get an efficient frontier, where the profit from the units traded outweighs the total risk you incur.
